# ¿Cómo retornar únicamente valores incorrectos o valores correctos?

Tags: python

al leer un archivo 'txt' con 'read_csv'y realizar un diagnostico de cada fila del archivo con el objetivo de encontrar las filas cuyas columnas no correspondan con las recomendadas me encuentro con el problema que también me muestra los valores positivos, es decir, en mi condición quiero que cuando exista UN solo valor incorrecto me cumpla la condición del 'if' así tenga valores correctos, en cambio no sé como hacer para que en el caso contrario 'else' solo funcione cuando TODOS los valores son correctos sin ningún incorrecto, ya que como tengo el código actualmente me muestra los valores correctos y también los incorrectos y no quiero eso, espero me puedan ayudar, adjunto código:

```
RECOMMENDED = 47

with open('prueba19082022.txt') as csv_file:
     reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = '|')
     for row in reader:
        if (len(row) != RECOMMENDED):
        
           print('El padrón:\n %r \n\nNO cuenta con el número de campos necesarios de acuerdo con las especificaciones para Persona Física \n '%row )
           print('El número de campos del padrón es: %r\n' %len(row))
        else:
           print('El padrón:\n %r \n\nCuenta con los campos necesarios de acuerdo con las especificaciones para Persona Física \n' %row)
```

El archivo leído cuenta con una fila de 49 columnas, por ende es incorrecto, pero al incluir una fila con el numero de columnas recomendadas me retorna los incorrectos y los correctos, solo quiero que me regrese o todos correctos (sin ningún incorrecto) o todos incorrectos (sin ningún correcto)

Comment: ¿Eliminar el `else` no te sirve? Así eliminas la acción asociada al dato correcto.

Comment: consulta, porque lees un .txt con csv?

Comment: No se entiende el enunciado. ¿Qué es un valor correcto e incorrecto? ¿Puedes poner una data de muestra y cómo debe ser salida?

Comment: @sysbot la pregunta correcta sería "por que tenés un archivo txt en formato csv?". Los tipos de archivo no definen que formato tienen. A lo sumo definen el formato que se ESPERA que tengan.